# Animation waits to fully finish to start it over

Tags: javascript, anime.js

Why is there a delay when the animation ends? I can't figure this out. When it finishes the first part, which is to make the width of all blocks equal 300px it does second part to return it back to 50px then it waits until the whole animation is over and only after that starts the another loop. Is there any way to make the blocks asynchronous? So that they don't wait for other blocks to finish the animation.

```js
anime({
  targets: '.b-main > div',
  width: [
    { value: 300, duration: 1200},
    { value: 50, duration: 1200}
  ],
  easing: 'easeInOutBack',
  duration: 5000,
  delay: function(el, i, l) {
    return i * 300;
  },
  loop: true
});
```

```css
.b-main > div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://animejs.com/lib/anime.min.js"></script>

<div class="b-main">
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b2"></div>
  <div class="b3"></div>
  <div class="b4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one animation that goes from 0% to 100%; at 0%, all blocks are at rest; at 100% as well; thus the delay.

The most obvious way would be to split your one animation into four, so the blocks are independent:

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.b-main > div');

targets.forEach((target, i) =>
  setTimeout(() =>
    anime({
      targets: target,
      width: [
        { value: 300, duration: 1200},
        { value: 50, duration: 1200}
      ],
      easing: 'easeInOutBack',
      duration: 5000,
      loop: true
    }),
    i * 300
  )
);
```

```css
.b-main > div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://animejs.com/lib/anime.min.js"></script>

<div class="b-main">
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b2"></div>
  <div class="b3"></div>
  <div class="b4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Is there any way to do this within the anime.js library? Creating a timeout looks weird, though I haven't thought about this, seems as the only viable solution so far. I know there's also `anime.stagger(100)` but it does the same, there's gonna be a delay at the end of each loop.